# Low Pass Filter to Isolate DC component

Tags: filter, fourier

I have a question based on low pass filtering. If I input a signal to this low pass filter, why does the output file have an AC (of very low frequency).

[image: LTSpice Circuit]

[image: Frequency Response of LPF]

The input signal is$$ v_i(t) = 2 + sin(2*pi*100Mhz*t)$$ According to the filter response, the $$ sin(100Mhz*t) $$ should be attenuated by a very large number, thus resulting in a coefficient << 0 and leaving the DC component of 2 left.  The output however is $$ v_o = 2 + sin(2*pi*0.1t) $$

---

**Where does that AC signal come from?**

[image: Time Domain of Capacitor Voltage]

Comment: Change "M" to "Meg".

Comment: In other words, your source is running at 100 millihertz = 0.1 Hz, which is obvious from the 10-second period.

Comment: Oh duh. That fixed it. It still has oscillation similar to that of a triangle wave, but with an amplitude of 0.2 mV which implies the large attenuation of the sinusoidal signal.

Comment: @jonk M is equal to Meg. When you select an FM station in your car does it say MHz or MegHz?

Comment: @HelenaWells Not in Spice, which is case-insensitive due to those ancient days in the late 1960's and early 1970's when we could not rely upon access to both lower AND upper case (see [Baudot code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baudot_code) for details.) Many punch card machines didn't support lower case and early terminals also didn't have lower case. So the Spice geniuses came up with Meg as a way of resolving that issue.

Comment: Omg how old is this platform?Download a newer one.My parents were born in 1970's

Comment: @Aaron The triangle wave is likely due, instead, to "numerical behaviors" related to truncation/rounding in floating point notation. You are using a very fast sine wave and a long period. If you'd like to see more "normal" plotting, try reducing the frequency by a factor of 100 and reduce the time by a factor of 1000 and see how that plots out.

Comment: @jonk yes a triangle signal is almost equal to a sine signal with very low frequency. Convert DC to AC doesn't produce a perfect sine wave, it is just little changes over time but not continuous discrete.

Comment: @HelenaWells I believe that ***all*** conforming Spice implementations use the name notation. So downloading a newer version won't help.

Comment: @Aaron maybe change the scale as well.

Comment: @HelenaWells There is a reason why "Meg" is universal in Spice for "mega." Spice itself only processes decks of cards. Back in the day, those were real cards you could hold in your hands. Today, this just means "one ASCII line of text." Spice is NOT a graphics program. Spice is NOT a schematic capture program. And while Spice may still support "plotting" using ASCII characters (I haven't checked if it still does that), most people would be very upset having to read ASCII-printed plots. So even the graphics display stuff is no longer Spice, as well.

Comment: @HelenaWells So all modern Spice programs, which now include specialized plotting and specialized schematic capture, still use the late 1960's technique in generating a "Spice Netlist" which is actually just a sequential list of ASCII text lines that can be processed by the core Spice algorithm, and that still today knows how to parse them (and only them.) If you use LTspice, for example, just go to "View/SPICE Netlist" and pop that up to see the netlist before processing with Spice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where does that AC signal come from?

The AC signal comes from the source, a passive linear filter can only change the amplitude and the phase, it cannot change the frequency of the waveform that it is filtering.

So the AC diagram shows the amplitude for all frequencies, and the chart below (in the OP) shows the output for one frequency.

Answer (score 1):

```
Where does that AC signal come from?
```

The AC signal comes from the source. Filters do not change the type of input signal, they change the amplitude and the phase of the input signal.

If you want it to convert it to DC you will need a rectifier as long as with a filter and then the filter will 'filter out' the input signals converting some of them to output DC with a detectable amplitude.